# How to organize MongoDB data by time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

I have an application that's saving data every second to MongoDB. This is important data, but holding data every second forever isn't necessary. After some time, I'd like to run a process (background worker) to clean up this data into hourly chunks, which includes every piece of data (1 per second) for each hour of that day. Kinda like Time Machine does on Mac.

From researching and thinking about it, there's a couple ways I can think of that I can make this happen with:

1. Mongo aggregators (not sure exactly how this would work)
2. Node background process with momentjs and sort by date, hour, etc. (really long time)

What's the best way to do this with MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Date Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) could be better option for your case. Given your schema as below

```
var dataSchema = new Schema({
  // other fields are here...
  updated: Date,
});
var Data = mongoose.model('Data', dataSchema );
```

Just save those data as the normal Date.

Then you can retrieve the hourly chunks through [aggregate operation in mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate), one sample code like,

```
MyModel.aggregate([
            {$match: {$and: [{updated: {$gte: start_date_hour}}, {updated: {$lte: end_date_hour}}]}},
            {$group: {
                _id: {
                    year: {$year: "$updated"},
                    month: {$month: "$updated"},
                    day: {$dayOfMonth: "$updated"}
                    // other fields should be here to meet your requirement
                },
            }},
            {$sort: {"date.year":1, "date.month":1, "date.day":1}} 
        ], callback);
```

For more arguments of `aggregate`, please refer to this [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate).